# By given that $AA^t$ and $A^tA$ are invertible and a matrix $A_{n\times k}$ prove that $n=k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

***Question:***

> By given that $A A^t$ and $A^tA$ are invertible and a matrix $A_{n\times k}$ prove that $n=k$.

---

$Proof.$

$\text{By given information we have that $A A^t$ and $A^tA$ are invertible. Therefore, we have: }$
$$\det\left( A A^{t}\right) \neq 0$$
$\text{Hence,}$
$$
\det\left( AA^{t}\right)\underbrace{=}_{ \begin{array}{l}
according  \ to \\det \ properties 
\end{array}}\det( A) \cdotp \det\left( A^{t}\right)\underbrace{=}_{ \begin{array}{l}
for \ each \ matrix 
\ A\\
there \ exist\\
\det A^{t} \ =\ \det A
\end{array}}\det( A) \cdotp \det( A) =\det^{2}( A) \neq 0
$$
$\text{So,}$
$$\det A\neq 0$$
$\text{Which means that A is invertible by definition, so we have $rank(A)=n$, therefore: }$
$$ColA=RowA=n$$
$\text{so we get:}$
$$n=k$$

---

Now, I am not sure that I can't deal with $\det A$ because it is undefined, however, I took at first $\det AA^t$ which is well defined. I will be happy to hear from you if my way is correct, or not and why. Thanks!

Comment: So $A \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times k}(\mathbb{R})$ right?

Comment: No, the identity you use is true only if both sides are defined

Comment: @Axel I think so.

Comment: @TimurBakiev So it is not true at all?

Comment: @Chopin The statement is true, but your proof is invalid. As a hint, I recommend considering how the rank of $AA^T$ compares to the rank of $A$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Oh I see, so if it was on an exam this probably wouldn't get any points right? I will try to think about what you say.

Comment: notice that the determinant is defined only on rectangular matrices (unless you use more complicated formulae) so you cannot use Binet here

Comment: @Exodd you mean square matrices?

Comment: @Chopin yes, as you can see, you have two conditions in your statement. This is not a coincidence. It is possible, that one product is invertible, and the other one is not. But if the formula was true, both products would have the same determinant.

Comment: @TimurBakiev Got you thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the assumed properties as $AA^t$ and $A^tA$ are invertible then,

$$\mathrm{rank}(AA^t) = n  \quad \text{and} \quad \mathrm{rank}(A^tA) = k  $$

Let's assume without loss of generality* that $k\leq n$, we have

$$\mathrm{rank}(A^t)\leq  k$$

(the rank of a matrix is always less than the number of its rows or its columns)

Hence,

$$\mathrm{rank}(AA^t)\leq \min(\mathrm{rank}(A),\mathrm{rank}(A^t))\leq k$$

But as $AA^t$ is invertible as stated above we have,

$$\mathrm{rank}(AA^t) =n$$

Therefore,

$$n\leq k$$

So it proves $n=k$.

---

*if $k\geq n$ then do the same with $A^tA$

Answer (score 1):

If $AA^\intercal \in \mathbf{M}_{n \times n}$ is invertible, that means that it has full rank $n,$ and since the rank of $A^\intercal \leq \min(k, n),$ we must have $k \geq n.$ By exchanging the rôles of $A$ and $A^\intercal,$ the result follows.